# PDO statement select where date less than error

Tags: php, mysql, date

I've spent 2 days trying to fix this - my date comparisons in MySQL aren't working when 
trying to bind values with the `<=` less than or equals operator.

I've narrowed it down to the second date field (from a much more complicated script that changes the prepared statement joins/groups/fields/conditions depending on the request..hence why I am referring to table.column and selecting from only one table below - it works either way) but I can't make sense of it. The exact code used to work on php 5.x but I have just upgraded to php7.2.27.

Take the below SQL statement:

```
$sth = $this->prepare("SELECT 
                        transaction.transactionid,
                        transaction.accountid,
                        transaction.userid,
                        transaction.billdate,
                        transaction.amount,
                        transaction.description,
                        transaction.confirmed
                    FROM transaction
                    WHERE    
                        DATE(`billdate`) BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate #date('2020-03-12')
                    ORDER BY billdate desc");
```

Trying to bind the following to it:

```
$terms = array(':startdate' => "2000-01-01",':enddate' => "2020-03-12");



foreach ($terms as $key => $value) {    
    if($value == (int)$value)
        $sth->bindValue("$key", $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    else
        $sth->bindValue("$key", $value);
}

var_dump($sth);
var_dump($terms);

$sth->execute();
$this->rowCount = $sth->rowCount(); 
var_dump( $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

This returns an empty array.

The table contains a handful of test rows. The below returns correctly:

```
 ... 
                DATE(`billdate`) BETWEEN :startdate AND '2020-03-12'
                ORDER BY billdate desc
```

Wrapping the dates in  `date('date')` seems to make no difference.

I've also tried this...

```
  DATE(`billdate`) >= :startdate AND 
  DATE(`billdate`) <= '2020-03-12'
                ORDER BY billdate desc
                ");
```

(Of course, changing the bound terms so that they mirror whatever I am using)

I need to be able to bind both variables.

Grateful for any pointers as I would love to avoid wasting another day debugging this!
Thanks

Comment: Note that `'2000-01-01' == (int)'2000-01-01'` returns TRUE. So you are probably binding dates as `PDO::PARAM_INT`.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Is `#date('2020-03-12')` actually in your sql code?

Comment: I think your probelm is that the actual values are not bound to the query until the execute is run. At that point `$value` is equal to the LAST thing it was set to in the loop, so you are getting `DATE(`billdate`) BETWEEN '2020-03-12' AND  '2020-03-12'`

Comment: You could always look in the MySQL logs and see what the query was that ran

Comment: If you have to so this `DATE(`billdate`)` does it mean that `billdate` is a text type not a date or datetime type?

Comment: This `if($value == (int)$value)` is definitely sending the code the wrong way in the IF

Comment: Thanks - this was all really helpful. The INT casting was the issue.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `CAST` to `DATE`:

```
WHERE billdate
BETWEEN CAST(:startdate AS DATE) AND CAST(:enddate AS DATE)"
```

And bind as `PDO::PARAM_STR`:

```
$sth->bindValue("startdate", "2000-01-01", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue("enddate", "2020-03-12", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```